# Where is the file of Android 2.1 (API 7) in the SDK folder?

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

I am looking for Android 2.1 library file in the **SDK folder**. My SDK manager shows that already the file is **installed**. So where is it?
Is it possible to access it?

Comment: You need to run on api-7 avd then create the avd of 2.1 version from avd manager.

Comment: Within the SDK folder platforms/android-7, since api level 7 corresponds to Android 2.1. Within that android.jar corresponds to your library I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<android-sdk-loaction>\sdk\platforms\android-7
```

There you can find **`android.jar`** corresponding to the API level 7.